# Backbone.js - extend router with beforeRoute filter

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to implement a before filter for my routes in Backbone.js.  I found the following code [here](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/494) -

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    route: function(route, name, callback) {
        return Backbone.Router.prototype.route.call(this, route, name, function() {
            this.trigger.apply(this, ['beforeroute:' + name].concat(_.toArray(arguments)));
            callback.apply(this, arguments);
        });
    }
});
```

However, I am not sure what I need to do next.  I'll need to define a function with the "before route" logic I want, but I don't understand how exactly it will be invoked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The overridden `route` function triggers an event named `beforeroute:routename`, then calls the original `route` function.  So if you have a route like this:

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: { 
        "": "home"
    },
    // ...
});
```

Then you would subscribe to the *beforeroute* event using:

```
var router = new MyRouter()

router.on("beforeroute:home", function() {

    // before route logic here...
    alert("Home route is about to get hit ...");
});
```

[Fiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/2QYrk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the other people like me are confused, why this not works. (anymore)
Since Backbone Version 0.9.10 it seems to be broken. (don't know really why)

But in Version 1.0.0 you can now use function literals instead of references to methods. http://backbonejs.org/#changelog

So you can do something before you call the Route...

```
routes: {
   'your-route' : function(){ if(yourCondition){ yourAction(); }}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is extending the Router.route function. Below an example for what I needed to do (to check user is authenticated). It's basically the original Backbone code (1.0.0) plus my custom code (marked with comments):

```
  Backbone.Router.prototype.route = function(route, name, callback) {
    if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);
    if (_.isFunction(name)) {
      callback = name;
      name = '';
    }
    if (!callback) callback = this[name];
    // here my custom code
    callback = _.wrap(callback, _.bind(function(cb) {
      if (name == 'login' || sessionModel.authenticated()) {
        _.bind(cb, this)();
      } else {
        this.navigate('login', {trigger: true});
      }
    }, this));
    // finish my custom code
    var router = this;
    Backbone.history.route(route, function(fragment) {
      var args = router._extractParameters(route, fragment);
      callback && callback.apply(router, args);
      router.trigger.apply(router, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
      router.trigger('route', name, args);
      Backbone.history.trigger('route', router, name, args);
    });
    return this;
  };
```

Notice `_.wrap` and `_.bind` so `this` is the one that you would expect when using the router. Otherwise I was getting a "this is undefined" error.